# Integrability using partition of unity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

For the following question, I'm using this definition of integrability:
[image]

We let $\Omega$ be an open set and $\mathcal O=\{U_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be an open cover of $\Omega$ s.t $Cl_\Omega(U_i)\subseteq \Omega$ is compact for every $i$.I want to show that if $\Omega$ and $f$ are bounded and $f$ is integrable on any compact subset of $\Omega$ then $\int_\Omega f$ exists.

This is my first time dealing with partitions of unity and this definition of integrability. Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: I don't think an open cover $\{U_i\}_i$ s.th. $Cl_\Omega (U_i)$ is compact exists in general.

Comment: @Targon You don't think it's possible or that it's generally true? This is just an assumption